# Disabling the back button on an activity when a dialogfragment is shown

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have an activity that shows a dialogfragment.
I've already set the dialogfragment cancelable to false, but the underlying activity still captures the back button press.
My underlying activity has overridden the onBackPressed method, but I don't want this to run when the dialogfragment is shown.

How do you disable the back button when dialogfragment is shown?
Do I check from activity onBackPressed method if dialogfragment is shown and ignore the back button press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to try like this..
Code paste in your activity

when you show `dialogfragment` that time set `shouldAllowBack` is false otherwise set is true

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if (!shouldAllowBack) {
       doSomething...;
   } else {
       super.onBackPressed();
   }
}
```

**or else**

follow this method

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(!shouldAllowBack && keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While showing your **`DialogFragment`** set `isBackDisable = true`

**and on your onBackPressed() :**

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (isBackDisable) return; // funtion will do nothing

        // do something from here. 
        Log.e("back disabled",false); // if isBackDisable = false then log will be printed
    }
```